# Finding subspace's base

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let W be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$:

$ \begin{cases} x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=0  \\ 2x_1+2x_2+x_3+3x_4=0  \end{cases}$

Find base of W and extend it to the base of $\mathbb{R}^4$

How to approach this question, detailed instructions appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you want to extend it? Also you should show your work on the problem (is it homework?).

Comment: it is not a homework, i have solely rref of this matrix ie. $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
 0 & -2 & -5 & -5
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: The matrix doesn't seem related to the question. Can you solve linear equations and check for linear independence?

Comment: @AlexR, it is the original matrix **after** it was reduced by rows: $\;R_2-2R_1\;$ .

Comment: @Alex, I meant the new, "unrelated", matrix's second row is obtained from the original one by substracting twice the first row from the second one...

Comment: @Timbuc Wich is inverted by $R_2+2R_1$^^ Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good, so let us take your rref matrix and continuefrom there. Second line means

$$-2x_2-5x_3-5x_4=0\implies x_2=-\frac52(x_3+x_4)$$

and then first line means

$$x_2+2\left(-\frac52(x_3+x_4)\right)+3x_3+4x_4=0\implies x_1=-2x_3-x_4$$

Since we're left with $\;x_3,x_4\;$ free (i.e., they're not "tied" to other variables), this system's solution's space (i.e., the matrix's kernel) is of dimension two. Now choose twice values for the free variables to obtain a basis for the kernel, for example

$$\bullet\;\; x_3=2\,,\,x_4=0\implies x_2=-5\;,\;\;x_1=4\implies v_1=\begin{pmatrix}4\\\!\!-5\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Choose now a pair of values for $\;x_3\,,\,x_4\;$ that'll yield a vector linearly independent with the above and you're done.

Finally, choose two other vectors that are lin. ind. with the ones you built to get a basis for $\;\Bbb R^4\;$ (secret: you can **always** expand to a basis in this way choosing from the canonical basis)

Comment: for free variable i am allowed to substitute any random values, right?

Comment: The first time, yes. The second one **no**, as the new set of values has to give something linearly independent. In my example, the first set was arbitrary, and the second one **cannot** be $\;x_3=2k\;,\;\;x_4=0\;$ as we'll get a vector that is lin. *dependent* in the first one.

Comment: thus i need to find a second vector that to chceck the fact that they are lin independent i need to do rref with those two vectors?

Comment: (-8, -12.5,3,2) is ok?

Comment: @kurkowski yes (can't you check by yourself?), but why those ugly numbers? wouldn't $$x_3=0\,,\,\,x_4=2\implies \begin{pmatrix}\!\!-2\\\!\!-5\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}$$ be nicer? and all the entries are integers... :)

Comment: right, i will check it by myself :), thanks a lot appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
The space $W$ is the kernel of the linear map given by the Matrix
$$\pmatrix{1&2&3&4\\2&2&1&3} =: A$$
Since the Matrix has full rank ($2$), you can solve the equation if you allow two unknown parameters. The solutions you will obtain can be written in the form
$$Ax = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$$
Where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. The basis you seek is $\{v_1, v_2\}$. To extend it to a basis of $\mathbb R^4$, chose two vectors $v_3, v_4$ such that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ is linearliy independent.